# Falta el destino de depuración visual estudio

Tags: c#

Actualmente estoy trabajando con visual studio 2019, en un programa de escritorio con el lenguaje de programación c# , ahora bien cuando trato de iniciar(compilar) el proyecto me aparece que Visual le hace falta el destino de depuración.

Pregunta: Como puedo solucionar el problema ?

No puedo usar visual studio 2022 por que el tipo de framework que se utilizo para trabajar este programa es Net.framework 4.5

Les agradecería si me podrían ayudar !SALUDOS!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No pierdas esta cuenta ;).. si se puede en [2022](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70022194/73749) . De paso, seguiste las instrucciones del cartel?

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!